# How to diff between large data files in data lake?

Tags: azure, csv, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

Each day we get large files from our source systems, lets call them extracts. These are large text or CSV files which are delimited by some character. The files are made available on a FTP server and we copy them each day into Azure Storage container, sorted into a folder per day.

After a while, the amount of files grew substantially, and so did the size of some of the files. Currently we are storing terabytes of extracts which contain 99% the same information.

I'm now looking for a way to create new datasets for each day that contains the diff with the previous day for that file. I hope to achieve a more efficient way of storing the data and be able to backload some of the tables in the datawarehouse more efficiently.

For each extract the key is known and can be used to comparison.
The resulting file should contain:

- the new entries
- updated records
- deleted records

For our ETL process we use Azure Data Factory, so ideally the solution would fit inside our current datawarehouse pipelines.

Sample inputs

Address_210825.csv

```
id,first_name,last_name,adress,city,state,postal_code
1,John,Doe,120  jefferson st.,Riverside,NJ,08075
2,Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila,PA,09119
3,John "Da Man",Repici,120  Jefferson St.,Riverside,NJ,08075
4,Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace  ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD,91234
5,,Blankman,,SomeTown,SD,00298
6,Joan "the bone",Anne,Jet,"9th,at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123
```

Address_210826.csv

```
id,first_name,last_name,adress,city,state,postal_code
1,John,Doe,120  jefferson st.,Riverside,NJ,08076
2,Jack,McGinnis,220 hobo Av.,Phila,PA,09119
4,Stephen,Tyler,"7452 Terrace  ""At the Plaza"" road",SomeTown,SD,91234
5,,Blankman,,SomeTown,SD,00298
6,Joan "the bone",Anne,Jet,"9th,at Terrace plc",Desert City,CO,00123
7,Chapman,Cecilia,711-2880 Nulla St.,Mankato Mississippi,MN,96522
```

In the mean time I found an usefull tool written in Python, [csv-diff](https://github.com/simonw/csv-diff). This tool can generate an output that lists the additions, removals, changes, and even added or deleted columns.

```
csv-diff Address_210825.csv Address_210826.csv --key=id --json > Delta_Address_210826.json
```

The result is:

```
    {
        "added": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "first_name": "Chapman",
                "last_name": "Cecilia",
                "adress": "711-2880 Nulla St.",
                "city": "Mankato Mississippi",
                "state": "MN",
                "postal_code": "96522"
            }
        ],
        "removed": [
            {
                "id": "3",
                "first_name": "John \"Da Man\"",
                "last_name": "Repici",
                "adress": "120  Jefferson St.",
                "city": "Riverside",
                "state": "NJ",
                "postal_code": "08075"
            }
        ],
        "changed": [
            {
                "key": "1",
                "changes": {
                    "postal_code": [
                        "08075",
                        "08076"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "columns_added": [],
        "columns_removed": []
    }
```

The remaining question is how to integrate this into Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Please edit your question to be specific. Currently, as written, it's very high level and broad. Also, there is no specific programming question (or sample input, sample output, etc). Lastly, please be careful of tagging; for example, you included `data-warehouse` but there is nothing specific to DW here.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for your suggestions. The question is indeed quite broad as it is partly architectual in nature, which components could or should I use. I updated the question, hopefully this clarifies what I like to achieve.